# VHDL Integer Range Output Bus Width

Tags: vhdl, quartus, intel-fpga

I'm currently working on writing a simple counter in VHDL, trying to genericize it as much as possible. Ideally I end up with a counter that can pause, count up/down, and take just two integer (min, max) values to determine the appropriate bus widths.

As far as I can tell, in order to get an integer of a given range, I just need to delcare

VARIABLE cnt: INTEGER RANGE min TO max := 0

Where min and max are defined as generics (both integers) in the entity. My understanding of this is that if min is 0, max is 5, for example, it will create an integer variable of 3 bits.

My problem is that I actually want to output this integer. So, naturally, I write

counterOut : OUT INTEGER RANGE min TO max

But this does not appear to be doing what I need. I'm generating a schematic block in Quartus Prime from this, and it creates a bus output from [min...max]. For example, if min = 0, max = 65, it outputs a 66 bit bus. Instead of the seven bit bus it should.

If I restricted the counter to unsigned values I might be able to just math out the output bus size, but I'd like to keep this as flexible as possible, and of course I'd like to know what I'm actually doing wrong and how to do it properly.

TL;DR: I want a VHDL entity to take generic min,max values, and generate an integer output bus of the required width to hold the range of values. How do?

If it matters, I'm using Quartus Prime Lite Edition V20.1.0 at the moment.

Note: I know I can use STD_LOGIC_VECTOR instead, but it is going to simulate significantly slower and is less easy to use than the integer type as far as I have read. I can provide more of my code if necessary, but it's really this one line that's the problem as far as I can tell.

I originally posted this on Stackexchange, but I think Stackoverflow might be a better place since it's more of a programming than a hardware problem.

EDIT: Complete code shown below

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY Counter IS
    GENERIC (modulo : INTEGER := 32;
                min : INTEGER := 0;
                max : INTEGER := 64);
    PORT( pause : IN STD_LOGIC;
            direction : IN STD_LOGIC; -- 1 is up, 0 is down
            clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
            counterOut : OUT INTEGER RANGE min TO max --RANGE 0 TO 32 -- THIS line is the one generating an incorrect output bus width
            );
END ENTITY Counter; 
-- or entity

ARCHITECTURE CounterArch OF Counter IS
BEGIN
    PROCESS(direction, pause, clk)
    VARIABLE cnt : INTEGER RANGE min TO max := 0; 
    VARIABLE dir : INTEGER;
    BEGIN
    IF direction = '1' THEN
        dir := 1;
    ELSE
        dir := -1;
    END IF;
    IF clk'EVENT AND clk = '1' THEN
        IF pause = '0'THEN
            IF (cnt = modulo AND direction = '1') THEN
                cnt := min; -- If we're counting up and hit modulo, reset to min value.
            ELSIF (cnt = min AND direction = '0') THEN
                cnt := modulo; --Counting down hit 0, go back to modulo.
            ELSE
                cnt := cnt + dir;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    counterOut <= cnt;
    END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE CounterArch;
```

Comment: This is not a VHDL issue, but a tool issue. Integers have no binary representation in VHDL itself, tools do that conversion themselves. As for std_logic_vector being slower than integer - hardly. Its more likely that a std_logic_vector will need more ram (a few more bytes). The biggest speedup is using variables rather than signals.

Comment: You need to post some code that has failed.Your general understanding is Ok, except that you don't get a 3-bit integer - you get a full integer in which only some values are valid. To get down to 3 real bits you need to convert to some bit-related type.

Comment: @Tricky I agree, I think it's definitely a tool issue at this point, Quartus is for some reason making a different assumption when using generics than when hardcoding in the range directly, and fighting with it to do what I want likely isn't worth it. I'll probably overhaul the code to use an unsigned for output if the vectors aren't going to be overly slow. I appreciate the advice!

Comment: @EML I added my code, although I think I've decided it's just a tool synthesis thing, Quartus is doing some assumptions about my code that changes between using generics and integer literals. I'm likely just going to change to using unsigned for the output bus with a generic width parameter (the idea of integers here was to set an easily customizable range, avoiding binary math of width -> range when using the counter, but it's not a necessity).
As for integers being full, are you sure? I've simulated it and the internal variables are definitely showing to have less bits when I specify.

Comment: VHDL has no binary representation of integers. Synth tools will convert to an appropriate number of bit for a limited integer range. But a simulated integer , even with limited range, will still be 32 bits (or implementation defined).